# Playing 2 musics through 2 different sound cards at same time

Tags: java, android, audio, usb, soundcard

Trying something pretty out of the box... I have a simple app with a button that when pushed, plays music out of the audio jack of my android tablet.

```
public void btn1 (View view) {
    MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.xxx);
    mp.start();
}
```

I've now added a usb audio interface (through a micro usb adapter) and I can hear audio out of it.

I'm able to list the sound cards with this

```
AudioDeviceInfo[] devices = audioManager.getDevices(AudioManager.GET_DEVICES_OUTPUTS);

for (AudioDeviceInfo device : devices) {
    int b = device.getId();
    int d = device.getType();
    CharSequence productName = device.getProductName();
}
```

How do I route music so that I can play 2 different music at once, one through usb and the other through the headphone jack?

Answer (score 2):

According to the `MediaPlayer` documentation, you can set the audio device using `setPreferredDevice` which receive an `AudioDeviceInfo` as a parameter, see https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#setPreferredDevice(android.media.AudioDeviceInfo).

You will then have to create one `MediaPlayer` to play on each device.

Comment: `setPreferredDevice` is added in API 28. Is there any other solution for < 28 ?

Answer (score 2):

it works about like this:

```
protected void playAudio() {
    this.playByDeviceIdx(0, R.raw.xxx);
    this.playByDeviceIdx(1, R.raw.yyy);
}

protected void playByDeviceIdx(int deviceIndex, @IdRes int resId) {

    /* obtain audio-output device-infos */
    deviceInfos[] devices = audioManager.getDevices(AudioManager.GET_DEVICES_OUTPUTS);

    /* check, if the desired index is even within bounds */
    if(deviceInfos.length < deviceIndex) {

        /* create an instance of MediaPlayer */
        MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, resId);

        /* assign a preferred device to the MediaPlayer instance */
        mp.setPreferredDevice(deviceInfos[deviceIndex]);

       /* start the playback (only if a device exists at the index) */
       mp.start();
    }
}
```

you could also filter for the headset jack plug/unplug event:

```
IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG);
Intent intent = context.registerReceiver(null, intentFilter);
boolean isConnected = intent.getIntExtra("state", 0) == 1;
```

sources: [me](https://stackoverflow.com/users/549372/martin-zeitler), based upon the SDK documentation for the [MediaPlayer](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer).

Comment: setPreferredDevice is added in API 28. Is there any other solution for < 28 ?